# Show Timestamp of first Occurence

Tags: influxdb

I have a db of hydrological data.

I wrote a cell in the influxdata panel to find the first occurrence where the measurement is above `17°`.

[image]

But now I don't want to display the value but the timestamp in the cell when the first occurence was:

```
from(bucket: "hydroAPI")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "hydro")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "temperature")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["loc"] == "XXXX")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._value > 17 )
  |> first()
  |> yield(name: "mean")
```

This code is working, but it shows just the value. I want to see the time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Single Stat visualization will always display what's in the `_value` column, so you need to replace that with your time.

Try adding this just before your `yield()`:

```
  |> drop(columns: ["_value"])
  |> rename(columns: {_time: "_value"})
  |> toString()
```

The first line drops the `_value` column so that you can rename the `_time` column in the second line. Since you probably don't want the timestamp in nanoseconds, the `toString()` on the third line will convert it into a human-readable form.